# Trouble adding conditions to MySQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Im new to PHP and MySQL and I am having problems writing what I want to happen here is my query :

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(op.total) as amount_sum
 , SUM(r.recurring_price) as recurring_price
 , op.subscription 
 FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order o 
 LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product op 
   ON(op.order_id=o.order_id)
 LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_recurring r 
   ON(r.order_id=o.order_id)
 WHERE order_status_id IN(" . implode(",", $implode) . ") 
   AND o.date_added >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH)";
```

I want to add this conditon to the query

```
AND op.subscription ='1'
```

I only want this to be added to the query if op.subscription equal 1.
Im using this for filtering so adding it to the main query doesnt work, but I dont understand how I can add that on. I think an if statement but do I have to set op.subscription to a variable? I know what I want to be able to do but I dont get how to write it properly in code

Comment: I added this and it returns the result I want but it throws a warning as well       if ($query['filter_subscription'] == '1') {
      $query .= "AND op.subscription = '1'";
  }

Comment: In the code above $query is a string but in your comment you are treating it as an array. I'm confused now.

Comment: @symcbean `$implode` is a complete unknown and if you assume that data's harmless you're making a huge mistake. PDO doesn't support binding to arrays, it's true, but spiking in the requisite number of placeholders is not hard. I also say "*any* user data" as it's highly probable `$implode` contains some kind of identifiers that probably come from a drop-down selection, e.g. `$_GET` or `$_POST` in origin.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add this conditon to the query

Concatenating it on the end of the query you already have would give the result you desire.

It is worth noting though,

- that adding this predicate in the WHERE clause, converts the first LEFT JOIN into a overly expensive INNER JOIN. Using an explicit INNER JOIN will be more efficient.
- you have quoted an integer value. If the underlying data type in the table is numerical then this is also innefficient. Although the optimizer should be able to handle this case with negligible overhead, you will come across problems if you blindly ignore data types. OTOH if the data type for the attribute is a varchar, then it suggests you are using the wrong data type.
- if you are going to use SQL reserved words (like `order`) for table or attribute names, then it's a good idea to enclose them in backticks so the SQL parser knows they are names not instructions.